# String to datetime: not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime, type-conversion

Ok so after some research I haven't found any way to solve my problem .

This is my String to Date conversion code:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime();
startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(this.items[5], "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

And this is the string I want to convert:

```
"22/2/2013 09:57:32"
```

But when I compile I have this error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pattern should be `"dd/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss"`

`MM` requires leading 0, which is not provided in your input string.

Comment: That was the problem ! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need a **single `M` instead of `MM` for month**. So format should be: `"dd/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss"`

Answer (score 1):

Just **one 'M' required for Month.** EX: **"dd/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss"**